# UWP Default Images

Tags: c#, uwp

Just starting out with UWP and I notice a lot of the apps use the same images / icons. Is there a standard image / icon set out there for us to use?

I have done a few searches and came up with nothing so far. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably talking about default symbols, they're not images, but are part of a special font

Here is official documentation and icons list:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn252842

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj662743

Comment: Thank you - this is what I was looking for.